# how get Kinect for windows work on ros?

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get a kinect for windows camera working with ROS, I'm using the driver openni_kinect, I don't have many experience with ROS or Linux, can anybody tell me where to start looking to get the kinect for windows working on ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40420/how-get-kinect-for-windows-work-on-ros?/) by [Lean2](https://answers.ros.org/users/1756/lean2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been [discussed previously](http://answers.ros.org/question/12876/kinect-for-windows/).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2